# Compare and sort Word entities (starting with vowel symbols) by consonants Java

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I have a hierarchy of classes Symbol, Word, Sentence, Text. Each class just contains a field with setters, getters, overridden equals and toString. These classes are kind of nested in each other by lists. It looks like this:

```
public class Word {
    private List<Symbol> symbols;
    public Word(List<Symbol> symbols) {
        this.symbols = symbols;
    }
    //getters, setters, toString
}
```

I need to find the words in the text which start from the vowel letter and sort them according to the consonant letter which goes after the vowel. I have been trying to get sentences and words from the text and then defined the words I need to sort. However, I do not know how to change compare in my helper method sort so it could actually compare consonant letters.

```
public void sortWords(Text text) {
        List<Sentence> sentences = text.getSentences();
        List<Word> words = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Sentence sentence : sentences) {
            words.addAll(sentence.getWords());
        }
        List<Symbol> symbols = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Word word : words) {
            symbols = word.getSymbols();
            Symbol first = symbols.get(0);
            if (first.isVowel()) {
                sort(words);
            }
        }
    }


    private void sort(List<Word> words) {
        Collections.sort(words, new Comparator<Word>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Word word1, Word word2) {
                List<Symbol> symbols = word1.getSymbols();

                for (Symbol s : symbols) {
                    if (s.isConsonant()){
                        //smth should be here
                    }
                }
            }

I would be grateful for any advice!
        });
    }
```

**Input:** 
Let's imagine that there is some kind of text here. Although I am not sure that you will find some sense in these words but there is text. It should be about programming but I did not figure out what to write exactly.

**Expected output (words starting from vowels are sorted by first occurrence of consonants):**
I, about, of, although, imagine, am, in, is, is, it, exactly

**My output:** there is not output yet because I have not finished the method

Comment: you need to be short and precise with your question. Please post expect output, current output and error if you are getting any

Comment: @Ravi I have added input and output to the question

Comment: You just showed us how to find the consonant in the first word.  Just do the same thing for the second word inside your if block.  Then, you'll have two Symbol objects to compare.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details of your Symbol class, so I have left part of the code for you to fill in. If the comparison results in `0`, you may want to still sort the words (`Comparator<String>` will help).

```
public void sortWords(Text text) {
    List<Sentence> sentences = text.getSentences();
    List<Word> words = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Sentence sentence : sentences) {
        words.addAll(sentence.getWords());
    }
    List<Word> wordsStartingWithAVowel = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Word word : words) {
        if (word.getSymbols().get(0).isVowel()) {
            wordsStartingWithAVowel.add(word);
        }
    }
    sort(wordsStartingWithAVowel);
}


private void sort(List<Word> words) {
    Collections.sort(words, new Comparator<Word>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Word word1, Word word2) {
            int result;
            Symbol firstConsonantWord1 = null; // get the first consonant of the first word
            List<Symbol> symbols = word1.getSymbols();
            for (Symbol s : symbols) {
                if (s.isConsonant()){
                    firstConsonantWord1 = s;
                    break;
                }
            }
            Symbol firstConsonantWord2 = null; // get the first consonant of the second word
            List<Symbol> symbols = word2.getSymbols();
            for (Symbol s : symbols) {
                if (s.isConsonant()){
                    firstConsonantWord2 = s;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(firstConsonantWord1 == null && firstConsonantWord2 == null) // both words don’t contain any consonants
                result = 0;
            else if(firstConsonantWord1 == null)
                result = -1;
            else if(firstConsonantWord2 == null)
                result = 1;
            else { // both words contain at least one consonant
                result = new Comparator<Symbol>(){
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Symbol symbol1, Symbol symbol2) {
                        // insert comparison of symbols here, depends on your Symbol class
                    }
                }.compare(firstConsonantWord1, firstConsonantWord2);
            }
            // if result is 0 you may want to do further comparisons (like a standard String comparison)
        }
    });
}
```